# BlackBerry JDE 5 Application Slowing Down

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I'm fairly new to writing BlackBerry applications, so maybe this is a stupid thing I'm overlooking. I have to use JDE 5 (client requirement) to support the older BlackBerry Curve 8520 phones.

What I am experiencing is that as soon as I place a `DateField` on my interface, the application slows down considerably, causing the UI to stutter. Even a simple layout that only has a single `DateField` and a button has the same effect. Then, as soon as I move on to the next layout, everything is fine again.

One of the layouts are created as follows (please comment if this is the incorrect way of doing it):

```
public void displaySomeLayout() {
    final ButtonField okButton = new ButtonField("OK");
    final DateField dobField = new DateField("Birthday", System.currentTimeMillis(), DateField.DATE);

    /* some other non-ui code */

    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            applicationFieldManager.addAll(new Field[] {
                    dobField,
                    okButton
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The application then just slows down a lot. Sometimes, after a minute of so it starts responding normally again, sometimes not.

The `displaySomeLayout()` method is called from the contructor of the `Screen` extending class. And then `applicationFieldManager` is a private `VerticalFieldManager` which is instantiated during class construction.

Comment: **Where** are you putting the code you show above?  Is it in the constructor for a `Screen` subclass, maybe?  And what does `methodToGetObjectArray()` return?  Does it return many, many objects, or just a few?

Comment: @Nate - It is not in the constructor. It is run when a specific method is called on that Screen (to update it's display). The `methodToGetObjectArray()` returns about 250 elements, but I have found that the phone handles it just fine. It's as soon as the `DateField` gets added that things go slow.

Comment: That's different from what you said in your question.  In the question, it says that adding the `ObjectChoiceField` **or** the `DateField` causes the problem.  If the `ObjectChoiceField` is not the problem, please don't show us that code.  Show us the code that **is** the problem, as you see it.  Also, you still didn't really answer the question regarding **where** the code you show is run.  Finally, 250 choices is actually a lot.  That sounds like a UI that users will hate to scroll through.  Is 250 really necessary?

Comment: @Nate Yes it is necessary unfortunately, they need to choose their country of residence. I will update my question wrt your other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the problem is in the code that you've shown us.  I think it's somewhere else.

However, here are a couple recommendations to improve the code you've shown:

### Threading

First of all, the code you show essentially **is** being run in the `Screen` subclass constructor.  There is almost no difference between this code:

```java
public MyScreen() {
   Field f = new ButtonField("Hello", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
   add(f);
}
```

and this:

```java
public MyScreen() {
   addField();
}

private void addField() {
   Field f = new ButtonField("Hello", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
   add(f);
}
```

So, because your code is being run in the screen class's constructor, it should already be running on the UI thread.  Therefore, there's no reason to use `UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater()` here.  Instead, just use this:

```java
public void displaySomeLayout() {
    final ButtonField okButton = new ButtonField("OK");
    final DateField dobField = new DateField("Birthday", System.currentTimeMillis(), DateField.DATE);

    /* some other non-ui code */

    applicationFieldManager.add(dobField);
    applicationFieldManager.add(okButton);
}
```

Sometimes, you **do** need to use `invokeLater()` to run UI code, even when you're already on the UI thread.  For example, if your code is inside the `Manager#sublayout()` method, which runs on the UI thread, adding new fields directly will trigger `sublayout()` to be called recursively, until you get a stack overflow.  Using `invokeLater()` can help there, by deferring the running of a block of code until `sublayout()` has completed.  But, from the *constructor* of your screen class, you don't need to do that.

### ObjectChoiceField

I'm also worried about the `ObjectChoiceField` you said you were using with 250 choices.  You *might* try testing this field with only 10 or 20 choices, and see if that makes a difference.

But, even if the 250 choice `ObjectChoiceField` isn't the cause of your *performance* problems, I would still suggest a different UI.

On BlackBerry Java, you can use the [AutoCompleteField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/AutoCompleteField.html).  This field can be given all the country choices that you are now using.  The user starts typing the first couple letters of a country, and quickly, the list narrows to just those which match.  I personally think this is a better way to get through a very large list of choices.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Just 2 things. It's a given that a method called from the constructor is 'basically' still in the constructor. The `displaySomeMethod()` is called after a certain event happens, not from the constructor, and that is why I am grabbing the UI thread. Then, the `ObjectChoiceField` does not seem to be my issue, just the `DateField`. I tried it on a screen with just the `DateField` and it still seems sluggish (JDE 5). Thanks for the heads-up on the `AutoCompleteField`, will definitely give it a go.

Comment: @NicoHuysamen, I think I was responding to the update to your question that said *"The displaySomeLayout() method is called from the contructor of the Screen extending class."*.  That's why I made the statement about the method running in the constructor.  If that first statement wasn't what you meant to say, that's fine.  However, with this *"certain event"* that you mention in your last comment, if that event runs on the UI thread, you still probably don't need the `invokeLater()` call.  If the event callback isn't on the UI thread, then you do, of course.